# Is there a grammatical difference between tú and vos?

Tags: pronombres, conjugación, voseo

Wikipedia lists both *tú* and *vos* as second person familiar singular pronouns. How can I differentiate between these in my fancy conjugation chart I am making?

(This is my first question here; I apologize if it's not very good.)

Comment: It would depend of where you plan to use your fancy chart. Argentina, Uruguay, Paraguay, parts of Bolivia? Hablá de vos. Most of the rest? Habla de tú.

Comment: If you want to know the differences between the verb conjugations in *tú* form and in *vos* form, [this](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3681/24236) might help. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they're conjugated differently. Here you have a chart, but, as a general rule (for regular verbs), vos works like vosotros but removes the last i, unless it's a third-conjugation verb (ended in -ir in infinitive).

Keep in mind that tú is the most commonly used one, and vos is mostly for Argentina and Uruguay (maybe somewhere else too, but not too common). Vosotros is like you guys, for more than one person, and only used in Spain. If you don't want to learn Castillian Spanish, maybe you want to study vos conjugations from zero instead of learning vosotros first.

[image]

Comment: *Vos* is also very common in Paraguay, widely used in several countries in Central America, and lots of regions in most countries of the Americas.

Comment: I am not so sure that it is "conjugated differently" as much as "in the countries where *vos* is common, the second person singular is usually conjugated this way." I mean, it would be correct for an Argentinian to say "tú tenés" or "vos sois".